# Getting started with JanusGraph Database, NodeJS and GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graph-databases, graphql-js, janusgraph

I'm searching on the web without any luck on how to fetch data from the JanusGraph database using GraphQL in NodeJS.

On Janusgraph.org, they have only shown how to use it with Javascript.

Can someone help me with how to use these technologies together?